# What does "Your old man's a ten" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the movie "*Coyote Ugly EXTENDED*", Gloria says these words to Violet about Violet's father Bill.

> Gloria: **Your old man's a ten, Vi**.
>
> Violet: Eleven, some days a twelve.

Context: Actually Bill came to Gloria's wedding with tie.

But I don't know what does this bold words means?

Comment: You seem to understand that “your old man” or “my old man” is a less-than-respectful reference to someone’s father and can also mean someone’s husband. This context carries a tint of surprise or disbelief and so is mildly ironic. “*The* old man” almost always refers to one’s own father or sometimes an elderly boss or superior. Similarly, “old lady” is usually a man’s wife but can sometimes mean someone’s mother, with both considered dated or even misogynistic language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of @Rüdiger's answer, it means that Gloria thinks that Bill, Violet's father, is hot, as in very, very attractive.

[image: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.]

On a scale of 1 to 10, 1 would be the worst and 10 would be the "best" or "perfect" quality ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_of_one_to_ten)).

Think of this like the gymnastics competition in the Olympics where [10 is a perfect score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_10_(gymnastics)).

In the meantime, Violet responds that her father is sometimes an eleven or a twelve to indicate that he's so good-looking that he has [broken the scale](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=BMS) (Definition Two).

And while Gloria had been judging based solely on looks (because as you say, he had been dressed up for the wedding), Violet is giving her rating to show her appreciation for her dad for his personality and as a person.

Answer (score 2):

It means that he is 10 in a scale from 1 to 10 as far as his appearence is concerned.